# How to import rest_framework to public Django project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, digital-ocean

i just wanted to publish my Django project but have the following problem:

```
ImportError at /
No module named rest_framework.views
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://165.227.154.0/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named rest_framework.views
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py in __import__, line 93
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/django/django_project',
 '/home/django/django_project',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 16 Nov 2017 19:30:11 +0000
```

If i run the project locally everything works. Now i have signed up at Digital Ocean and created a one click app. Started their server and uploaded all my files properly via FileZilla into the server directory.

When I enter the IP adress into my browser I also get the reply: It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.

But after I uploaded my files, installed the new apps and added the urls,
I receive the Error from above.

Apparently, the rest_framework module can not be imported and I don't know how to fix it.

Is here someone who can help me?

Thanks and kind regards

Marcel

Comment: Did you try `pip2 install djangorestframework`? Perhaps, default python/pip version is 3 and rest framework installed for python 3 if it is so.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't install the django-rest-framework library in the server. You have to check which package you have installed in your local environment, usually you should use pip to freeze all the dependency to a file called requirement.txt, and when you push the codes to server, you can use the requirement.txt file to reproduce the same environment as your local envirionment.